# Apache on WampServer Keeps Crashing

Tags: apache, wampserver, httpd.conf

I run a medium traffic website that seems to be crashing all the time and I have to restart because it either doesn't load or cloudflare displays 520 error.

Anyway I have searched up this error and they say to enable KeepAlive, but I haven't seen that option in the httpd.conf.

My server info ( Yes I know linux is useful but I am using many windows softwares on my server computer as well ). I am running apache that is integrated with wamp server.

8GB of RAM and i7-2600, so it's a fast enough server.

Fast enough Bandwidth as well.

Here is the error log, let me know if you need any more info, thank you!

```
[Fri Jan 03 16:02:06.265860 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 35404:tid 452] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Fri Jan 03 16:02:06.265860 2014] [core:notice] [pid 35404:tid 452] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Fri Jan 03 16:02:06.266861 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 35404:tid 452] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10260
[Fri Jan 03 16:02:06.660883 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10260:tid 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:50.867886 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 35404:tid 452] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:52.868000 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10260:tid 332] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:52.915003 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 35404:tid 452] AH00430: Parent: Child process 10260 exited successfully.
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:55.018123 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32116:tid 452] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:55.018123 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32116:tid 452] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:55.018123 2014] [core:notice] [pid 32116:tid 452] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:55.020124 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32116:tid 452] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9012
[Fri Jan 03 19:13:55.355143 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9012:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:50.496864 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32116:tid 452] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:54.203076 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9012:tid 328] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:54.238078 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 32116:tid 452] AH00430: Parent: Child process 9012 exited successfully.
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:55.553153 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9676:tid 452] AH00455: Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) PHP/5.4.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:55.554153 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9676:tid 452] AH00456: Server built: Feb 22 2013 22:08:37
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:55.554153 2014] [core:notice] [pid 9676:tid 452] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.4\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4'
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:55.555153 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9676:tid 452] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1272
[Fri Jan 03 20:41:55.885172 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1272:tid 328] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Its not in your httpd.conf because the default value for KeepAlive is on. So you already have that set by default. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,120592,120646#msg-120646

Answer (score 2):

You could try these parameters in your `httpd.conf` file. It has helped with this sort of situation in the past and it may help yours.

```
# AcceptFilter: Windows, none uses accept () instead of AcceptEx ()
# And do not recycle sockets between connections. This is useful
# Network interfaces for which the pilot is defective, and for
# Some network providers like vpn pilots or filters
# Anti-spam, anti-virus or anti-spyware.
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

Comment: Hello sir thank you for the reply! Ok, so I have searched my httpd.conf but I don't see AcceptFilter in there anywhere when I try searching for it. Would you like me to just add it in anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it does not exist in the default `httpd.conf`. So add it, but make sure it is not within any specific existing section. Maybe best to add it at the bottom of the file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly If I off the filters does it make my SSL vulnerable? Is it safe?