# Laravel 5 and XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, openssl, ssl-certificate, laravel-5

I have been developing an application using Laravel 5 with XAMPP without any problem for the past 2 weeks. All of a sudden I have encountered a problem. Apache restarts itself whenever I try to open the Application. I have an application using Laravel 4.2 and it is running seamlessly. So does other applications with no framework.

here is my apache_error log

```
[Mon Apr 13 11:17:55.124340 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 244:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Apr 13 11:17:56.553187 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 244:tid 232] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Apr 13 11:17:56.990707 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 244:tid 232] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Apr 13 11:19:24.202850 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2660:tid 260] AH00428: Parent: child process 244 exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Mon Apr 13 11:19:26.188766 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 2660:tid 260] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Apr 13 11:19:26.427117 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2660:tid 260] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 13 11:19:26.427117 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2660:tid 260] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 11:50:08
[Mon Apr 13 11:19:26.428120 2015] [core:notice] [pid 2660:tid 260] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Apr 13 11:19:26.812682 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2660:tid 260] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6196
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Note: this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928989/xampp-apache-error) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24097498/error-running-apache-after-xampp-install) didn't solve my problem.

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917022/apache-on-wampserver-keeps-crashing